# CakePHP Add To ARO When Model is Created

Tags: cakephp

I have the following ARO tree:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Aro tree:
---------------------------------------------------------------
  [1] rental_registry_users
  [2] rental_registry_admin
    [3] User.1
    [11] User.7
  [4] rental_registry_owner
    [5] User.3
  [6] rental_registry_agent
    [7] User.4
    [8] User.5
    [9] User.6
  [10] rental_registry_management_company
```

When a new user is created, I would like to automatically add them to the 'rental_registry_admin' ARO.

This is what my Users model looks like:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

/**
 * User Model
 *
 */
class User extends AppModel {

  var $actAs = array('Acl' => array('type'=>'requester'));

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
  public $displayField = 'username';

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
  public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
      'email' => array(
        'rule' => array('email'),
        //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
        //'allowEmpty' => false,
        //'required' => false,
        //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
        //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
      ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
      'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
        //'allowEmpty' => false,
        //'required' => false,
        //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
        //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
      ),
    ),
  );

/**
 * beforeSave method -- executed before model is comitted to the database
 * @return true
 */
  public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
      $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
      $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
      );
    }
    return true;
  }

  public function parentNode() {
    switch ($this->data[$this->alias]['role']) {
      case 'admin':
        return 'rental_registry_admin';
      case 'owner':
        return 'rental_registry_owner';
      default:
      case 'agent':
        return 'rental_registry_agent';
    }
  }

}
```

However when a new user is saved, they are not added to the ARO.  What am I missing?  This code was based off of the example on page 285 of the CakePHP book.  The user is not getting added to any of the AROs, so it's not that it's getting assigned to the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I switched how permission levels was being handled.  Instead I added a 'role' field to the user table and used that to determine access inside the controller.

Comment: The best way is to create a "user_group_id" field in your user table and then handle permissions based on the UserGroups table, if you dont need your end users to be able to change permissions you can also check out https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-sanction